# how to use IIS and website hosting

Tags: sql, iis, webserver, web-hosting

I am new website servers and hosting and just after some help clearing some stuff up. 
Firstly if I use a website server on my computer ie. IIS is that the same as using a web host such as host puppa? and if so does that mean I don't need to use a web hosting company? 
Secondly what hosting/ server do i need to use to run SQL and MySQL in my website? 
Is there any good tutorials that run through all of this stuff for beginners as I am quite confused?

Comment: If you wish, you can host the website and database in the same computer yourself (beware for security settings though)... It depends..you just need to enable IIS and install the database server on the computer

Answer (score 1):

IIS is a web server such as apache or nginx. It's a Microsoft product and supports ASP.NET pages.

You can use it instead of a web host, but you have to make sure that your computer is reachable from the internet if you want global access. There is also some setting for what interface and port you want IIS to listen on, that should be set to your external IP address and port 80 for HTTP.

If you are behind a router with NAT, you have to use port forwarding to redirect port 80 requests to the router into your IIS.

As SQL server you can use Microsoft SQL Express or MySQL for example.

Personally, I use WAMP on Windows machines, which gives me everything I need: Apache, MySQL and PHP.

Furter reading: http://www.howtogeek.com/177129/beginner-geek-how-to-host-your-own-website-on-windows-wamp/ (wamp only, but I mentioned alternative applications above)

**Edit 1:** If your ISP gives you dynamic IP addresses (which is the common) you have to use some kind of dynamic DNS updating, you IP address might change.

Also, of course, if you shut your PC down, the site goes down as well.